# Tomcat to JBoss AS configuration migration

Tags: tomcat, jboss, migration

I am working on a automated tool which helps in migrating  apps from Tomcat to JBoss AS by creating all the deployment descriptors and server configuration xmls required for JBoss AS by parsing the respective Tomcat xml files.

I would like to know,what all xmls have to be parsed and modified on JBoss AS to make the migration tool work for all types of migrations (that is , I want to make it a generic tool).It would have to cover JDBC, JNDI, JMS topics,queues etc.

A list of all the XMLs that would have to be modified and any sample structure for each XML is what I am looking for..thanks in advance for the help..

Also if we already have a open source tool available for this,it would be great if someone can point out...

Comment: Could you please join the [SwanLoom project](https://github.com/OndraZizka/jboss-migration/wiki)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a list of XML files to change in JBoss AS 7:

- `configuration/standalone.xml`

Easy right? :)
However, it's not recommended to work with standalone.xml directly - it's just a way to persist the configuration and may change over time.
What is supported and backward compatible is CLI commands and [Management API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Management+API+reference).

There are already two tools which help with migration.
I'd suggest you rather join these efforts. I personally spent few weeks developing SwanLoom, and Brad Davis and others spent 2 years developing WindUp:

1) [JBoss SwanLoom](https://github.com/OndraZizka/jboss-migration/wiki/) - automated migration tool aimed to server configuration migration.

2) [JBoss WindUp](http://windup.jboss.org/) - a reporting tool aimed to application migration - deployment descriptors etc.

And finally, there's a new site dedicated to JBoss migration: http://www.jboss.org/migration/

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely take a look at the [JBoss WindUp migration assistant](http://windup.jboss.org/index.html).  It currently focuses on other application servers (WebLogic, WebSphere, etc) but certainly could be adapted to use Tomcat as well.